# What should our policy on research-level theoretical questions be?

Tags: discussion, policy, migration, cstheory

This site encompasses computer science at all levels. This includes research-level questions about theoretical computer science which are also on-topic on our sister site [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

In principle, the existence of other sites does not affect the scope of this site. I recommend reading Shog9's blog post [Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/). In particular (excerpted):

> - [Do not do] scope Gerrymandering: attempting to micromanage what’s on-topic in order to avoid overlap with other sites or simply drive away users seen as undesirable.
> - Do leave comments on questions that might get better answers somewhere else.
> - Don’t attempt to scavenge on-topic questions from other sites by asking the moderators there to migrate them to yours. Again, there’s no harm in leaving a comment suggesting that a question would be a better fit somewhere else. But focus on the questions that aren’t on-topic, or aren’t getting answered – snatching someone’s question (or answer) away without any forewarning is a slap in their face.

Given these considerations, are there any circumstances where we would migrate questions asked here to the TCS site? Here are a few things we might decide; this is of course not an exhaustive list of possibilities, and this question is a call for proposals (and a first attempt at finding a consensus), not a referendum.

- Never migrate questions to TCS.
- Only migrate questions to TCS if they would be on-topic there and they are the kind of “soft questions” that are generally not welcome on Stack Exchange, but work in “elitist” communities like TCS (such as [big-list](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) and [research-practice](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-practice)).
- Offer to migrate questions that would be on-topic on TCS if they have had no satisfying answer after a few days and the asker agrees.

Answer (score 6):

Your option three fits my opinion:

> Offer to migrate questions that would be on-topic on TCS if they have had no satisfying answer after a few days and the asker agrees.

We have snatched badly-treated questions in scope overlaps from SO and math.SE, there is no reason why we should not act likewise in the other direction. Questions like [this here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/has-anyone-found-polynomial-algorithm-on-hamiltonian-cycle-isomorphism) are probably better off on cstheory.SE because they have the/more experts.

We have to be careful not to migrate non-research-level questions to them, though. That might require careful communication as, arguably, most of us are not really qualified to decide that.